# How do I keep program running until quit option is chosen

Tags: loops

I've tried everything. Testing in python fiddle online. This as far as I can get, it works but wont loop and I can press anything above 5 to quit/get thank you for using jys area calculator.

```
print "Welcome to Jys area calculator!"
print "What is your name?"
name = raw_input() 
print "Hi",name, ",please select a formula using the letter it represents or press 6 to quit. Your options are:"
mylist = ['1 for square', '2 for rectangle', '3 for circle', '4 for triangle','5 for elipse']
for elem in mylist:
        print elem
shape = input()
if shape == 1:
        print "Okay",name, ",to work out area of square first enter length and then breadth of square"
        a = input()
        b = input()
        c=a*b
        print "The area of your square is",c
elif shape == 2:
        print "Okay",name, ",to work out area of rectangle first enter length and then breadth of rectangle"
        a = input()
        b = input()
        c=a*b
        print "The area of your rectangle is",c
elif shape == 3:
        print "Okay",name, ",to work out area of a circle enter the radius"
        r= input()
        c= 3.14159265359*(r*r)
        print "The area of your circle is",c  
elif shape == 4:
        print "Okay",name, ",to work out area(c) of triangle first enter height(h) then base(b) length"
        h= input()
        b= input()
        c=0.5*h*b
        print "The area of your triangle is",c
elif shape== 5:
        print "Okay",name, ",to work out area of ellipse first enter length then breadth."
        a= input ()
        b= input ()
        c= 3.14159265359*a*b
        print "The area of your elipse is",c
else:
    print "Thank you for using Jys area calculator",name,"!"
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I suppose by `loop` you mean, that the script re-runs after a calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't see any loop to ask for the next number? I must admit I don't know python fiddle, but in most languages you could write something like:

```
bool Looping=true;
while(Looping)
{
  shape=input();
  if shape==1
    calc and display
  if shape==2
    calc and display
  else
  {
    print "bye bye!";
    Looping=false;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried everything

The most basic concept about loops are the loop operators itself, and in your code I only see a simple input plus some ifs/else if. Where is the loop?

Your logic should be (pseudo logic)

```
input = get_value()

while(input not equal 6) {
  if(input equal 1) { .... square logic }
  else if(input equal 2) { ... }
  ...
  input = get_value()
}
print "Thanks for using the application"
```

The while loop will execute this sequence until the user set the value as six. As you can see, every time the application will ask for a new value, before it starts the loop again.

Here is your code with the while loop:

```
print "Welcome to Jys area calculator!"
print "What is your name?"
name = raw_input() 
print "Hi",name, ",please select a formula using the letter it represents or press 6 to quit. Your options are:"
mylist = ['1 for square', '2 for rectangle', '3 for circle', '4 for triangle','5 for elipse']
for elem in mylist:
        print elem

shape = input()

while shape != 6:
    if shape == 1:
            print "Okay",name, ",to work out area of square first enter length and then breadth of square"
            a = input()
            b = input()
            c=a*b
            print "The area of your square is",c
    elif shape == 2:
            print "Okay",name, ",to work out area of rectangle first enter length and then breadth of rectangle"
            a = input()
            b = input()
            c=a*b
            print "The area of your rectangle is",c
    elif shape == 3:
            print "Okay",name, ",to work out area of a circle enter the radius"
            r= input()
            c= 3.14159265359*(r*r)
            print "The area of your circle is",c  
    elif shape == 4:
            print "Okay",name, ",to work out area(c) of triangle first enter height(h) then base(b) length"
            h= input()
            b= input()
            c=0.5*h*b
            print "The area of your triangle is",c
    elif shape== 5:
            print "Okay",name, ",to work out area of ellipse first enter length then breadth."
            a= input ()
            b= input ()
            c= 3.14159265359*a*b
            print "The area of your elipse is",c

    shape = input()

print "Thank you for using Jys area calculator",name,"!"
```

I strongly recommend you to learn more about algorithms and programming rather than just using a language. Knowing a language is not the same as being a programmer on that language.

Comment: AWESOME!!!!!!!!! Thank you. Works like a charm. Super helpful, with the actual code and my learning. Thanks again, much appreciated. :) :) :)